# Retrieve strings from previous activity

Tags: android, android-activity

if I have an application with 5 activities, each of which produces a datum (a string for example), how can I make the sixth activity retrieve these 5 strings of each activity? if I use the intent system it just takes the data of the previous activity and that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use SharedPreferences for saving a string of a particular activity by using a distinct key for that. Once you reach 6th activity, you can retrieve all of them using their respective keys.

Comment: Thank you, I use successfully SharedPreferences for my app!